# PuTTY - how to enter both username and password?

Tags: ssh, putty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I typo my username when ssh-ing, is there a way to go back and change it?](https://superuser.com/questions/279917/if-i-typo-my-username-when-ssh-ing-is-there-a-way-to-go-back-and-change-it)

When logging in using PuTTY, I sometimes use a wrong or mistyped user name. PuTTY does not let me re-enter the correct user name (contrary to what the standard linux console does), so I have to close the PuTTY window and start a new one, which is annoying.

How do I configure PuTTY or maybe the underlying ssh session so that I have to enter both user name and password if the login process fails?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/279917/if-i-typo-my-username-when-ssh-ing-is-there-a-way-to-go-back-and-change-it

Comment: I did not find the existing question, because I specifically searched for "putty" related questions. The existing question could be improved by re-phrasing its title.

Comment: Suggestion @indrek: The existing question could be improved by re-phrasing its title, so that PuTTY is mentioned. It is not a ssh problem because when using a console, one can always enter CTRL-C CTRL-R which restarts the ssh command, allowing entering of the correct user name again. Easy enough. But with PuTTY, the equivalent process is several mouse clicks and key presses.

Comment: This question has an answer that might help:  https://superuser.com/questions/989166/putty-automatically-log-in-into-different-sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to right-click on the puTTY title and select 'new session'.
(Basically starting anew)

[image: SSH window via puTTY]

Just for the record, puTTY behaves the same as GNU/Linux's ssh.

When you log on via the console your try to log in locally.  SSh is not used.
When you use ssh from a Linux host or via puTTY both ask again for the password, but keep the username.

PS: you can configure puTTY to store the username in the session. No need to type it, and not chance for typos.

Comment: Although it appears there is no fix for this problem, the feature to store the user name is useful, didn't know that.

Comment: You can also set it up to log in with an SSH key, which can get you in without typing a password, FWIW ...