# Putty automatically log in into different sessions

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

When you have to check a large number of hardware in your network and dont want to type in your username and Password every time after starting putty, changing the IP and starting the session, what can you do? obviously starting putty and jumping right into a session with Login and Password Parameters in the properties of the .exe would not work

Comment: Use SSH keys. Or a saved configuration.

Comment: Or certificates, if your infrastructure is set up for them. Or other kind of single-sign-on.

Answer (score 1):

> SOLVED

I just found this Logon settings in the property after right click on server ip/name in MTPuTTY left side server list.

[image: MTPuTTY property settings]

Answer (score 1):

If your system is not accessed by anyone else you can store the details in a small script and run it to open multiple PuTTY sessions

```
@start /b putty.exe -ssh 12.10.0.1 -l <username> -pw <password>
@start /b putty.exe -ssh 10.11.0.1 -l <username> -pw <password>
```

You can save the file as, say ***sessions.bat*** and execute it by double-clicking it or from command line.

Please note that you need to enter the full path of putty.exe file or place the script in the same folder as the putty file.

Hope it helps.