# Why can I not correct a misspelled username at beginning of SSH session in Putty?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, putty

I am having an issue with the Putty SSH Client. When I misspell a username on the remote server it puts me in an endless password prompt.

Is there any way to escape this without having to close the connection and reconnect?

Comment: you can obtain sourcecode at [the official PuTTY download page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) and change it, if you like.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the solutions listed [here](http://superuser.com/questions/279917/if-i-typo-my-username-when-ssh-ing-is-there-a-way-to-go-back-and-change-it)?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways to avoid this issue.

If you use the same username for all the servers you connect to,  when you load up putty under saved sessions load the default profile and before connecting to a server go to:

Connection -> Data in the left hand menu and set Auto-Login username to the username you always connect as.  Go back to session click on Default Settings and save.

Otherwise if you use a separate username for each server,  create and save a session for each one and do the same as above in Connection -> Data.